# How to divide the textdata with fixed width and assign column names in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a text data as follows

data
        V2

```
 1 12384793849384u39840598093580985309580359803958035
 2 55132531453215532532523451325235324521435132523452
 3 52353251253253245132444444444444553241524351243532
 4 23515123532532512345214512345213551253245432542135
 5 23532115124542352335122222222435451435143251234542
 6 13245432543215214352152234513425234555512311235412
 7 1327r6tr87t987rt38r7t93487y32987y3287y39o8r2y9874r
```

i have another key file as follows

keyfile

```
      header                      startkey    endkey
 1    Claim Unique ID                    0     12
 2    Provider CCN Number               13     18
 3    Beneficiary Hic Number            19     29
 4    Claim Type Code                   30     31
 5    Claim From Date                   32     41
```

So, now i want to extract 0 to 12 letters of each row and assign it to claim unique id variable, 13 to 18 letters for provider ccn number variable and in the same way for all the variables

Expected output

```
  ClaimUniqueID  ProviderCCNNumber  BeneficiaryHicNumber  ClaimTypeCode ClaimFromDate
  132364748474   u74635             54673829273           87            7474747474  
  231763987435   123433             12353244513           23            1343434444  
  193274674474   143243             23342535435           23            1243213424
```

Tried

```
 data <- read.fwf("cclf_text_file.txt",widths=10000)
 keyfile = read.csv("cclf_key_file.csv",header = T)

 fixed_length = function(input_data,key_file,output_data){
 input_data[] = Map(substr,input_data[keyfile$header],keyfile$startkey,         keyfile$endkey)
 filename = paste(deparse(substitute(output_data)), ".csv",sep="")
 write.csv(input_data,file = filename) 
 }
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work (It's hard to tell without a reproducible example)

```
keyfile <- read.csv("cclf_key_file.csv",header = T)
data <- read.fwf("cclf_text_file.txt",widths=keyfile$endkey - keyfile$startkey + 1)
names(data)<-as.character(keyfile$header)
```